# Assets folder files aren't updated when I update the app

Tags: android, apk, android-assets

I have an app v1.0 that uses a local database saved in assets folder... I have updated my app to version 1.1, in the new version the internal db has different entries.

Unfortunately the installed app continue to use the database of version 1.0 and I must unistall the app and install again to use the database of the latest version.

Is really a bad thing force the buyers to unistall the application and reinstall the new version... Why the assets files  aren't updated with the new version?

**EDIT**

I have understand that this issue happen because the database is created from assets file and only if isn't already created, this is my DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; 
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME = "MyDatabaseFile";
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        // If database not exists copy it from the assets

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!mDataBaseExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        // Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        // mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
        // SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

How could I avoid this issue when I'll upgrade the app on PlayStore, without renaming the db file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have an app v1.0 that uses a local database saved in assets folder

No, you have an app v1.0 that *copies* a database "saved in assets folder" and creates a local database from it. Hopefully, [you use `SQLiteAssetHelper` for this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

> Why the assets files aren't updated with the new version?

The asset file *is* updated. You are not doing anything to fix up the copy that you made. If you use `SQLiteAssetHelper`, it has a procedure for handling such upgrades.

Comment: @KinkLore: I recommend replacing that code outright with `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the DATABASE_VERSION parameter in your DB helper class everytime you make changes to the database ? Check that. It is usually defined in the helper class like this :

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Comment: I'll try this... however I'm confused. When the app is updated and overwrite, the dbfile in asset file and consequently the database loaded from this file, why isn't updated?

Comment: My answer was just a part of the things that need to be done properly to handle a database upgrade (assuming you did the rest correctly). I agree with the detailed explanation by CommonsWare above. I would recommend that you follow the article http://joshhendo.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-sqlite-database-upgrade.html and compare it with what you are doing in your code. This article will help you understand the process of how the upgrade works.